# Security popups because of setting caller-allowable-codebase " * " with the latest jre update since 15th April 2014 patch

Tags: security, manifest, java-7, java-8, self-signed

Security popups are being displayed so frequently because of setting caller-allowable-codebase " * " which is already mentioned in the critical patch release notes with the latest jre update since 15th April 2014.

https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/jdk_8u5_and_jdk_7u55

Is there a way to avoid them as these popups are affecting the users with jre7u55 and jre8u5

Comment: Is there a reason you specified `*` instead of a domain?

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox to remember the "Allow/Do Not Allow" decision in 1.7.0_55 and 1.8.0_5, which will suppress this popup in the future.  However, there does not seem to be a straight-forward way to push this decision to users machines.

You could also have your users downgrade to 1.7.0_51, which seems to be the only version of Java that supports "*".

What we have been doing is modifying "*" to a space-separated list of host names:

```
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: foo.bar.com *.bar.com localhost
```

Source:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html